# Time-efficient Gameloop in J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, game-loop

I've done a series of questions about J2ME Game developing, and in a recent one, Neil Coffey commented

> As a side issue-- do you REALLY want
>   to do 100 ticks/second in a J2ME game?
>   As I think sb has mentioned, you
>   should really also sleep to the next
>   desired wake-up point, not a fixed
>   duration each time.

For some reason, that thing stuck in my mind and now I want the answers, what do I need to make my gameloop sleep to the *desired wake-up point*, I don't really know where is that point xD (theoretically speaking).

For the sake of feedback, this is a simplified version of my gameloop:

```
public void run() {
    Graphics g = this.getGraphics();
    while (running) {
        long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastLoop;
        lastLoop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        input();
        this.level.doLogic();
        render(g, diff);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            stop(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you decide that you want to render every 10 milliseconds, then you:

```
loop {
  - record current time; render
  - do input/logic
  - check the current time, and calculate elapsed time
    - if less than 10 ms has elapsed, calculate the remaining time (10 millis - elapsed time); sleep for this duration
}
```

I understand that there may be issues with timer resolution (for example, Thread.sleep(10) may not sleep for exactly 10 ms; and System.currentTimeMillis() may not return results with granularity down to 1 ms).  This is platform dependent.

Answer (score 3):

There is an excellent article on game loops [here](http://dewitters.koonsolo.com/gameloop.html), if you haven't read it already.

From my experience writing J2ME games, you'll want to minimize how much you do anything in a game loop, as a poorly written game loop can quickly drain a phones puny battery.  That is, if you're rendering ever 10 milliseconds, make sure to check to see if anything has changed, and if not, skip it.